# Facebook Open Graph Aggregation with Layout Style Map

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I didn't find any documentation on how to create an aggregation with *Layout Style* **Map**. There are some input fields in the og app settings I don't understand what they are for.

For single actions these are:

- Numbers: Header, {number selector} (count, expires_in), units
- Highlighted Points
- Route: {Geo Point [] selector}

And for multiple actions there is only one field which is

- Contributing Point: {Geo Point selector}

What is the meaning of all these fields and how do I use them? Any explanation, documentation or tutorial would be great! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally found the documentation I've been searching for so long: <strike>https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/</strike>

**Update** (new url)**:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#maplayout

Comment: URL outdated. You know if it was moved, or simply deleted? :/

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard It seems the information was moved and scattered. I've updated my answer with the best match I could find.